# Stop the test and return to the beginning of the method

Tags: android, methods, if-statement, while-loop, break

How to stop a test (while or if) the method and start again.

In short, how to stop the test method and start again.
I tried to call the method Testex (); more like it not for the rest of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that this is what you want: 
http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html

Assert will terminate the test and cause it to fail if the condition is not true.